# application should not be shared to other users

Tags: java, android, security, privacy

I want to make sure that once my application is installed on any android device, after retrieving that apk from that device and installing on other devices (by sharing pre installed apk) should not work.
I thought of using IMEI, but that could not be predefined in application (because I may give the application to several users). **I want my application usage to be restricted to my selective users only**. This is an offline application, so can't expect to check it through network.

Comment: If you can require the user to go online after installation, you can hit a server once then to obtain some sort of key which is derived from an identifier of the device, and only offered to those who have created some sort of account with you.  To install on a different device they would have to repeat that process for the new identifier, which would require logging into their account again. If you don't want them to register lots of devices, have your key expire after some period of months, and warn them in advance that they will need connectivity to get a new one as it approaches expiration.

Comment: Can you get unique device IDs of your users?

Answer (score 3):

In short words, you are basically out of luck here with offline app.